# I need a custom javascript variable in my GTM container to return true if the user allows location sharing

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I need to fire a tag when user has shared the location to the browser. I tried the below code as custom javascript variable in my GTM Container but did not work.

```
navigator.permissions && navigator.permissions.query({name:'geolocation'}).then(function(PermissionStatus) {
    if(PermissionStatus.state == 'granted'){
         return true;
    }else{
         return false;
    }
})
```

Comment: no idea if that is your only problem, but for a custom javascript variable you would need to wrap this in an anonymous function.

Comment: @EikePierstorff yes I need a fucntion that returns true if location is shared and false otherwise. The above code works fine when i checked in google chrome console but doesnt seem to work in the google tag manager

Comment: The thing is that the above code is an expression, not a function. For a custom javascript variable you need an anonymous function that returns a value, i.e. "function() { return some_value }", where your code would go inside the curly brackets.

Comment: @EikePierstorff yes exactly, i need the code to go inside that curly braces.

Comment: the code you wrote in your question is THE code that goes inside that curly braces.

Comment: @Matus i tried that but i am getting undefined

Comment: That's because your code returns a promise (".then") - you will need to find a solution for that.

Comment: @Matus could you tell me how to get the value from this promise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution would be to implement the code you have as custom HTML tag  and push promises' result as an event to dataLayer - then you can fire your tag on this new event. For example:

```
<script>
    navigator.permissions && navigator.permissions.query({name:'geolocation'}).then(function(PermissionStatus) {
        if(PermissionStatus.state == 'granted'){
             dataLayer.push({event: 'permissionGranted'})
        }else{
             dataLayer.push({event: 'permissionDenied'})
        }
    })
<script>
```

Then you will need to fire your tag on this custom event "permissionGranted".

More about custom events [here](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7679219?hl=en).